# FormGroup addControl doesnt update the controls in the view

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have an existing FormGroup with some controls which are showed in the template.
Now, I want to replace the FormGroup with another FormGroup with slightly different fields.

```
 this.removeAllControls(); // removes Controls of this.formGroup
 const newFormGroup: FormGroup = FormGroupFactory.createFormGroup(......);
    this.setControls(newFormGroup);
```

First, I remove all controls of this.formGroup. Then, I create a new FormGroup with some new Controls and some stayed the same (same FormControlName but different value and validator).

After that, I call:

```
private setControls(newFormGroup: FormGroup): void {
    Object.keys(newFormGroup.controls).forEach(key => {
        const formControlCopy: FormControl = newFormGroup.get(key) as FormControl;
        const newFormControl: FormControl = new FormControl(formControlCopy.value, {updateOn: formControlCopy.updateOn, validators: formControlCopy.validator}, formControlCopy.asyncValidator);
        this.formGroup.addControl(key, newFormControl);
    });
}
```

After, I have added the new controls, the template looses the connection to the FormControls... so if I try `this.formGroup.get(nameWhichWasInTheOldAndTheNewFormGroup).setValue('..')`

The value is set, but the view does not change....